# url Slug php and htaccess rewriting issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, slug

I'm trying to create a slug to jump from home page to `View Deal` with the title as a slug.

What should be my htaccess code?
and here is my php link:

```
<a class="nad-prodlink" href="deal/Pairs-of-incredible-Body-Slimming-Pants">view</a>
```

Comment: <a class="nad-prodlink" href="deal/Pairs-of-incredible-Body-Slimming-Pants">view</a>

Comment: what is exact url of your page?

Comment: http://www.teamvouchers.com/deal/Pairs-of-incredible-Body-Slimming-Pants